# How to send a Json POST request in Java for Blitline?

Tags: java, json, post

Hi guys I m trying to send a Json POST request in Java to perform a task with the image processing service Blitline. However I m keep getting an error :

IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://api.blitline.com/job

In the following link there is an example code but doesnt work in my case.

http://blog.blitline.com/post/21295009377/post-to-blitline-api-with-java

Anybody worked with blitline could give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The response json content may contain a clue, something like:

```
    String responseData = connection.getResponseMessage();
```